# count words in all the classes of a file

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have some files in Persian. All of them contain a lot of sentences, then a "tab", then a Persian word, again a "tab" and then an English word. The English words show each sentence class. I have to count the number of each word in Persian sentences in all of the classes. For example, how many times the word "دانشگاه" occurs in "passion" class and how many times it occurs in "salty" class. (some files have more than 2 classes). The code I wrote counts the words just once in the file. How can I change it that it returns the words count, as I described above? (hint: I JUST need the count of words in the sentences NOT the Persian and English words after "tab").

[image]

```
from collections import Counter

corpus = []
with open("T.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        t = line.strip().split("\t")
        corpus.append (t)
        for row in corpus:
            wordcount = Counter(row[0].split())
        print (wordcount)
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r88hglemg7aot0w/F.txt?dl=0

[image]

The result is as above picture. But the thing I want should be like below for all of the words:
passion {"دانشگاه": 1 , ...}
salty {"دانشگاه": 0, .....}

Comment: Is there a particular part you're having problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not the most efficient way of doing it but it is more clear in terms of what it is doing.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

#find all Persian words and save them in a set
vocab = set()
classes = set()
with open("T.txt", encoding='utf-8') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        t = line.strip().split('\t')
        sentences = t[0]
        class = t[2]
        classes.add(class)
        for word in sentences.split():
            vocab.add(word)
class_word_count = defaultdict(dict)
for class in classes:
    for word in vocab:
        class_word_count[class][word] = 0
#now start counting
with open("T.txt", encoding='utf-8') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        t = line.strip().split('\t')
        sentences = t[0]
        class = t[2]
        for word in sentences.split():
            class_word_count[class][word] = class_word_count[class][word] + 1
print(class_word_count )
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yasini/Desktop/14.py", line 11, in <module>
    classes.append(clas)
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: you could've changed append to add.

Comment: for the rest of my work I need to achieve each word and its number. I tried but I couldn't. I appreciate a lot if you tell me how. Actually this is a pert of Naive bayes algorithm for classification.

Comment: typo: part not pert